# How can I sign in and get access token of Microsoft Graph API for personal account using com.microsoft.graph.microsoft-graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to ask a question about authentication of Microsoft Graph API.

I know that I have to get access token to use Microsoft Graph API.I want to get an access token so that it can be used with a personal Microsoft account,because I think about use of Microsoft Graph API in B to C usecase.

Therefore, I created a sample source code to acquire an access token by the following two methods.
（The language used is Kotlin.）

- (a) Method using com.microsoft.azure.msal4j
- (b) Method using com.microsoft.graph.microsoft-graph

Then, while the method (a) allowed me to sign in with a personal Microsoft account and obtain an access token, I couldn't sign in with a personal Microsoft account using method (b).When I execute the code in (b) and try to sign in, the following error is displayed on the screen.

```
Error Message:
You cannot sign in here with a personal account.
Please use your work or school account instead.
```

The implementation example of (a) is as follows. This implementation was created with reference to the following site.

site: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/wiki/Acquiring-Token-Interactively

```
    fun getAccessTokenByMSAL(
        appId: String,
        scopes: List<String>
    ): String? {
        val scopeSet = HashSet<String>()
        scopes.stream().forEach { scope ->
            scopeSet.add(scope)
        }
        val app = PublicClientApplication
            .builder(appId)
            .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common")
            .build();
        val params = InteractiveRequestParameters
            .builder(URI("http://localhost:8080"))
            .scopes(scopeSet)
            .build()
        val result = app.acquireToken(params).join()
        return result.accessToken()
    }
```

The implementation example of (b) is as follows. This implementation was created with reference to the following site.

site: https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java#InteractiveProvider

```
    fun getAccessTokenByGraphSdk(
        appId: String,
        scopes: List<String>
    ): String? {
        val credential = InteractiveBrowserCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(appId)
            .redirectUrl("http://localhost:8080")
            .build()
        val authProvider = TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, credential)

        return try {
            val url = URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me")
            authProvider.getAuthorizationTokenAsync(url).get()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Error occured")
            println(e)
            null
        }
    }
```

What I would like to ask this time is the difference in behavior between (a) and (b).
Why can't I sign in with my personal account in case (b)?
How can I personally sign in and get an access token using com.microsoft.graph.microsoft-graph?
I would appreciate it if you could answer.

Comment: What value are you providing for authority? If you are using personal Microsoft accounts to login you need to use authority as 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common' see the reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jeevan_MSFT_Identity's Advice, finally I solve the issue.

I had to set authority host to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common' if I need to use personal account.

Fixed code is as follows.

```
    fun getAccessTokenByGraphSdk(
        appId: String,
        scopes: List<String>
    ): String? {
        val credential = InteractiveBrowserCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(appId)
            .redirectUrl("http://localhost:8080")
            .authorityHost("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common") // Add this line
            .build()
        val authProvider = TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, credential)

        return try {
            val url = URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me")
            authProvider.getAuthorizationTokenAsync(url).get()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Error occured")
            println(e)
            null
        }
    }
```